# Trivial Solution in Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in the following differential equation:

$xy' + y = y^{-2} $

we can see that $y=1$ is a solution that always satisfies the equation regardless of the value of $x$.

Do we call this a trivial solution? Or do we only call "$y=0$" a trivial solution?

If we only call $y=0$ a trivial solution, what does that make $y=1$ in the equation presented above?
I thought there would definitely be a specific mathematical term for this "$y=1$" since this is a solution that satisfies the equation regardless of the boundary conditions. Is there another term for this $y=1$ which always satisfies the differential equation above?

Would appreciate it if anyone could provide an accurate explanation.

Comment: I agree with @kdefaoite.The constant solution is trivial in the sense that it makes the differential character of the equation disappear ($y=y^{-2}$). So "a trivial solution is $y=1$" seems fine. IMO, you could even say "this equation admits *the* trivial solution", where $y=0$ is *implied*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually "trivial" means "extremely easy" or in another sense "does not carry the true meaning of the problem we are trying to solve". I'll discuss this notion with respect to ODEs below.

The general form of an $n$th order ODE is $$F(x,y',y'',...y^{[n]})=0 \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Let's take a special case where the equation is linear and homogeneous:
$$p_0(x)y+p_1(x)y'+...p_n(x)y^{[n]}=0$$
Where $p_i$ are arbitrary functions. Then $y=0$ is always a solution, regardless of what the $p$'s are. Because of this, we call the $y=0$ solution "trivial" because it carries no meaning in regard to the $p$ functions - that is, *given* the solution $y$ we would have absolutely no way of making any sort of conclusions as to what the $p$'s might be. However, it *might not* always be a solution to **(1)**, and therefore might not be trivial to another kind of ODE. So what we call "trivial" really depends on context. Your $y=1$ solution is certainly trivial with respect to the more general ODE $$x\frac{\mathrm{d}^ny}{\mathrm{d}x^n}+y=y^\alpha$$
But it might not be trivial in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the equation as
$$
y'=\frac{y^{-2}-y}{x}=\frac{(1+y+y^2)(1-y)}{xy^2}
$$
you see that $y=1$ is a root of the right side. This is called an equilibrium or stationary point, sometimes also fixed point.